# Magento 2.1 lost with shops

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, magento2

i need to make a magento configuration. I explain you what i need :

- 1 website for all the market
- Different providers that propose theirs products
- User can look all providers at the same time or go shop by shop between providers
- 1 Payment for the users
- The providers get the monney if an item is in the cart of the user and all i want behind (transfert order etC...)

So i search on google and magento doc, but 'm lost in all the website / shop possibility. Is it easy to do what i say ? how can i do it ? thx for help :)

Comment: Nothing in Magento is easy ... nothing...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to a specific programing problem; it could be migrated to magento.stackexchange.com but even then it's a bit vague.